# Absolute Galois groups for finite extensions

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, extension-field

Let $L/K$ be a finite field extension. Is it true that we can embed $G_L$ into $G_K$?

I think the most natural choice would be to choose the restriction map, so

$$ G_L \to G_K, \quad \sigma \mapsto \sigma|_{\bar{K}}.$$

But I still do struggle to show whether this map is injective or not. Assume we have two different elements $\sigma_1, \sigma_2 \in G_L$. Then there exists an $x \in \bar{L}\setminus L$ with $\sigma_1(x) \neq \sigma_2(x)$. But to show injectivity, I have to find such an element $x$ in $\bar{K}$. Can I rescue this argument?

Thank you!

Comment: If $L/K$ is finite then $\overline L = \overline K$

Comment: Dear @Diglett, Are you choosing $\overline{K}$ to be the separable closure of $K$ in $\overline{L}$? Separable closures are not unique or canonical in general, so you have to be precise about choosing them and should not assume any relationship between them without additional elaboration.

Comment: Is the source of your worry here that $L$ may not be separable over $K$?